# What does this sql injection try to do and how can I check if it worked?

Tags: sql, sql-injection, drupal-8

our provider noticed us about the following requests:

> www.example.com 46.72.247.70 - - [04/Oct/2018:15:08:17 +0200] "GET
>   /jp-ja/node/249%27%20or%20(1,2)=(select*from(select%20name_const(CHAR(71,65,81,75,112,108,70,121,116
>   ,110,105),1),name_const(CHAR(71,65,81,75,112,108,70,121,116,110,105),1))a)%20--%20%27x%27=%27x
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 6227 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"

Since I literally understand nothing and hence dont know how to check if it did something: What does this sql injection try to do and how can I check if it worked?

Comment: I don't know what the attacker was trying to do.  He was doing a `SELECT` of some kind, which would only retrieve information from some table.  It should not have done any nasty DML stuff, like `DELETE`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only interesting part when talking about SQL is the middle one:

> (select*from(select%20name_const(CHAR(71,65,81,75,112,108,70,121,116 ,110,105),1),name_const(CHAR(71,65,81,75,112,108,70,121,116,110,105),1))a)

Which, written in readable, looks like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
  SELECT NAME_CONST(CHAR(71,65,81,75,112,108,70,121,116,110,105),1),
         NAME_CONST(CHAR(71,65,81,75,112,108,70,121,116,110,105),1)
    ) a
```

The subquery of this query sets two constant fields, both named CHAR(71,65,81,75,112,108,70,121,116,110,105) which, after applying ASCII, translates to "GAQKplFytni" and sets them the value 1. Then the main Query just picks everything from the subquery (so it doesn't change anything).

On SQLFiddle it does not seem to work, since NAME_CONST requires a STRING input as the first parameter.

Unless there is some magic behind the whole thing, this query has no right to work.

Comment: Perhaps there used to be some subtle bug in `name_const` that this is designed to trigger. Bear in mind that a lot of these attacks will try hundreds or thousands of different queries against practically every server on the internet trying to find unpatched machines. E.g. there are still lots of script kiddies out there.

Comment: thank so much guys

Comment: [Source](https://firegenanalytics.com/2017/12/splunk-review-121017/): _It seems that the purpose of these SQL commands is just to determine if the target is susceptible to SQL injection attacks_

Comment: In my case, it was CHAR(73,73,97,83,97,110,68,81,72,76,66,88)